# Merging multiple rows grouping multiple columns values

Tags: sql

Basic SQL I know, I've found a workaround but I'm sure there's a better way.

I've got a table where account_id can be assigned two type of entities A and B, and I want to group them out in the output table:

**Table A:**

```
+------------+--------+--------+
| account_id |   A    |   B    |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 68129726   | Mario  | null   |
| 68129726   | null   | Silvio |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

**Output Table:**

```
+------------+--------+--------+
| account_id |   A    |   B    |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 68129726   | Mario  | Silvio |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

I'm sure there's an answer already, it's just I don't know the "technical" name for this operation.

My solution (more of a workaround really):

```
SELECT DISTINCT account_id, MAX(A), MAX(B)
FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY account_id
```

Is there a better, more proper way of doing this?

Comment: is it possible to have same account_id, holding two different names in entities A. e.g. `account_id -> 68129726 A -> Mario B -> null;
account_id -> 68129726 A -> John B -> null;` etc...

Answer (score 1):

The "more proper" way is an explicit `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT account_id, MAX(A), MAX(B)
FROM TABLE A
GROUP BY account_id;
```

The only other alternative I can think of is a join:

```
SELECT a.account_id, a.a, b.b
FROM table a JOIN table b
ON a.account_id = b.account_id AND a.a IS NULL AND b.b IS NULL;
```

I prefer the aggregation, but under some circumstances, the `JOIN` would be faster.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff I actually forgot to add that :) Is it the BEST way?

Comment: @TheoGonella . . . Without the `SELECT DISTINCT`, I think so.

Comment: you mean that DISTINCT shouldn't be there? Wouldn't I get the origin table in that way?

Comment: @TheoGonella, since you do GROUP BY account_id, your result will already be without duplicates, even without SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: makes complete sense @jarlh, sorry for the dumb question haha